# MATLAB2014b `fitglme` causes error on intermediate results

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, matlab, glmm

(This post is [a duplicate from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28253403/matlab-fitglme-causes-error-on-intermediate-results) as there was no response there)

MATLAB R2014b's library function `fitglme` is acting up. It seems to be producing invalid intermediate results, cf. following run:

```
>> formula = 'Y ~ A + (1|B)';
>> glme = fitglme(ds,formula,'Verbose',2);

Starting PL iterations.

  ============================================================================================
  ITER     FUN VALUE    NORM GRAD    NORM STEP    CG TERM        RHO        TRUST RAD   ACCEPT
  ============================================================================================
     0    -1.798e+308    0.000e+00    1.250e+03       BNDRY    +1.747e+305    1.250e+03     YES

         Infinity norm of the final gradient = 0.000e+00
              Two norm of the final step     = 1.250e+03, TolX   = 1.000e-12
Relative infinity norm of the final gradient = 0.000e+00, TolFun = 1.000e-06
EXIT: Local minimum found.

  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  PL ITER      LOGLIK       ||ETA||    ||ERR: ETA||    ||W||    ||ERR: ETA->MU->ETA||
  -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1       NaN    2.797e+00       NaN    4.000e+00          NaN
Error using
classreg.regr.lmeutils.StandardLinearLikeMixedModel/validatey (line
299)
NaN or Inf values are not allowed in y.

Error in classreg.regr.lmeutils.StandardLinearMixedModel/set.y (line
265)
                newy = validatey(slme,newy);

Error in
classreg.regr.lmeutils.StandardGeneralizedLinearMixedModel/fitUsingPL
(line 1661)
                        slme.y = ypw;

Error in
classreg.regr.lmeutils.StandardGeneralizedLinearMixedModel/refit
(line 4315)
                    [sglme,cause] = fitUsingPL(sglme,numIter,kappa);

Error in classreg.regr.lmeutils.StandardGeneralizedLinearMixedModel
(line 4288)
                sglme = refit(sglme);

Error in GeneralizedLinearMixedModel/fitStandardLMEModel (line 1317)
        slme =
        classreg.regr.lmeutils.StandardGeneralizedLinearMixedModel(X,model.y,Zs,Psi,model.FitMethod,dofit,dostats,args{:});

Error in GeneralizedLinearMixedModel/fitter (line 891)
        model.slme = fitStandardLMEModel(model);

Error in classreg.regr.FitObject/doFit (line 220)
            model = fitter(model);

Error in GeneralizedLinearMixedModel.fit (line 2411)
        model = doFit(model);

Error in fitglme (line 389)
    glme = GeneralizedLinearMixedModel.fit(T,formula,varargin{:});
```

where

```
ds = 

       Y    A        B
  2.7971    1        1      
  2.3801    2        1      
  1.7125    1        2      
 0.13291    2        2      
 0.70898    1        3      
  1.3898    2        3      
 0.55758    1        4      
 0.43072    2        4      
 -1.3622    1        5      
 -1.4441    2        5      
 -0.0781    1        6      
 0.48738    2        6      
-0.77377    1        7      
 -1.4891    2        7      
  -1.149    1        8      
-0.70913    2        8
```

Where the A and B variables are nominal.

Plese help. I am running thousands of these fittings, and I cannot tell why e.g. the data set here does not work, while e.g. the following DOES:

```
ds = 

        Y    A        B
   2.8272    1        1      
   2.4091    2        1      
   1.6445    1        2      
  0.11834    2        2      
  0.66552    1        3      
   1.3342    2        3      
  0.53821    1        4      
  0.35225    2        4      
  -1.3412    1        5      
  -1.4446    2        5      
-0.092893    1        6      
  0.44625    2        6      
   -0.805    1        7      
  -1.5075    2        7      
  -1.1167    1        8      
  -0.7717    2        8
```

Comment: I'm quite surprised it didn't get a response on SO. I put a bounty on it over there, but perhaps you'll see an answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your iteration log seems to indicate that `fitglme` is having difficulty converging using its default parameter initialization for your first problem. Consider changing the initial point by using the `'StartMethod'` name/value pair:

```
glme = fitglme(ds, formula, 'verbose', 2, 'StartMethod', 'random');
```

Also, you seem to be fitting a Normal distribution. In this case, you should also be able to use the function `fitlme`.

Comment: Random seed did the trick!